# Error with function round php

Tags: php

I'm having trouble using the tool round the php, my case is similar to that section:

```
if($array ['situation'] == 'A') { 

$value += round($array['value'], 3);

} elseif($array ['situation'] == 'B') {

$value -= round($array['value'], 3);

} elseif($array['situation'] == 'C') {

$value += round($array['value'], 3);

}
```

There comes a time that the variable `$value` is to zero and instead is generating a large number such as 7.105427357601E-15, and the values that come are not great that way. Does anyone know what can it be?

Comment: 1. *large number such as 7.105427357601E-15* A large negative number yes 2. Which if statement do you enter ? 3. What is the output of `var_dump($value);` and `var_dump(round($array['value'], 3));` ?

Comment: $value of the output variable is equal to 1, and the output of var_dump(round($array['value'],3)) is also 1, but rather the result is 0, this being a large number